# opencart safari and internet explorer can not login?

Tags: internet-explorer, safari, opencart

I use opencart 2.2.0.0, it works fine with chrome, opera, firefox,

But does not work with safari and internet explorer 11.

Specially on iphone, safari, use can not login with correct user name and password

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer of opencart owner [Cannot add items to cart in latest iPhone 6 - Safari](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/2398)

I realized, the issue is not opencart， the issue is brower itself, it is caused by 
privacy setting, cookies not allowed, or cache issue.

First should check browser setting, allow cookies, (cookies used by login process)

Second, clear cache.

for example, iphone safari, you can go

Launch the Settings app from the Home screen of your iPhone or iPad.
Scroll down and tap on Safari.
Click Block cookies (under privacy & security section), choose always allow

or
Now scroll all the way to the bottom and tap on Advanced.
click website data, click show all data, click Remove all website data at bottom,
this will clear all cached cookies etc....

after doing above, opencart can login as normal in iphone safari